# archive-post type content not showing

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type, and its not showing the content with in my archive page(Videos), What am i doing wrong. here is the code. I appreciate the help guys.

THE VIDEOS POST TYPE

```
<?php


/**
 * CUSTOM POST TYPES
 */

add_action('init','videos_post_type');

function videos_post_type(){

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'Videos', 'text-domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'Video', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new'             => _x( 'Add New Video', 'text-domain', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Video', 'text-domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Video', 'text-domain' ),
        'new_item'            => __( 'New Singular Name', 'text-domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Videos', 'text-domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Videos', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No Plural Name found', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Plural Name found in Trash', 'text-domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Singular Name:', 'text-domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Videos', 'text-domain' ),
    );


    $args = array(
        'labels'                   => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'description'         => 'description',
        'taxonomies'          => array(),
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'menu_icon'           => null,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => array('slug'=>'videos'),
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'supports'            => array('title', 'thumbnail','page-attributes','editor')
    );

register_post_type('Videos', $args);
```

}

THE archive-videos template

```
<?php get_header();?>
<section class="videos">
    <div class="video_banner">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/image 2.jpg';?>" alt="">
            <h3 class="videos_title"><?php wp_title('');?> </h3>

            <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'videos',
                'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
                'post_per_page'=> 4


                );
            $videos = new WP_QUERY($args);

            ?>

                <?php if ( $videos->have_posts() ) :?>







                <?php while ( $videos->have_posts() ) : $videos-> the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part('loop', 'videos' );?>
                <!-- post -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- post navigation -->
                <?php else: ?>

                <?php endif; ?>




        </div><!-- END CONTAINER-->
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your post type to `videos`. This should solve your problem.

Here is a few golden rules for naming conventions when creating custom post types and custom taxonomies

- never use camelcase, all characters should be lowercase
- never use special characters, except underscores
- stay clear of reserved names

Also, drop your custom query and just use the default loop. If you need to change anything in the main query, rather use `pre_get_posts`

Comment: i didn't work, The banner image shows, the admin bar shows, and the header shows, its just not fetching the content

Comment: What doesn't work. Have you changed both your custom post type name and changed back to the default loop?.

Comment: Do a check, what does `var_dump($wp_query->posts);` return

Comment: i changed my post type name to videos

Comment: Do you have posts inside your custom post type. And remove your custom query and replace it with the default loop

Comment: yeah it doesnt do anything, i just have to read the post type template again

Comment: Also, flush your permalinks again

Comment: let me try your advice

Comment: omg lol, everything was working all along, it turned out that i needed to close my video_banner div after the h3 title, silly me

Comment: I appreciate your help though, i really do.